# Clear Tag property on object copy operation

Tags: matlab, stateflow

I'd like to use a stateflow object's `Tag` property to hold persistent data relative to that object. The problem arises when the user performs a copy of the object using a right-click/drag/release of the object. Under this (and all copy operations), the `Tag` property is not cleared. If anyone has a solution, I'd be most interested in hearing it.

(For completeness, on the other copy operations (context menu, edit menu) I can modify `sfcall.m` (in private, yikes!) to clear the property).

Comment: Can you please provide some example code?